# echo vs echo intval PHP

Tags: php

Please can some one explain the result differences below

```
echo intval(1e10);
```

Output                  `1410065408`

```
echo 1e10;
```

Output `10000000000`

Comment: http://php-tutorial-php.blogspot.in/2012/10/intval.html
this may be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A signed integer has a maximum value. On 32-bit systems, that's 2^16 or 2147483647. When `intval`-ing a number that's larger, it will overflow. The value you found can also calculated:

```
php > echo 1e10 % (2147483647);
1410065408
```

Comment: 2^32 is 4294967296! You're talking about signed integers.

Comment: Please note that as of PHP/5.5 this might also affect [64-bit PHP on Windows](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=137002754604365&w=2).

Answer (score 4):

From PHP Manual:

> The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is 9223372036854775807.

intval will truncate the number

Comment: Maybe, but when I do this: `intval(intval(1e10)+1)`, I do get 1410065409, so apparently we are not talking about maximums.

Comment: intval() handles overflow differently depending on the type of the argument. `intval('10000000000') = 2147483647; intval(1e10) = 1410065408;` intval(float) yields essentially non-defined result when the argument is beyond the range of int. Look at the comments below

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
<?php

echo 'intval: ' . intval( 1e10 ) . PHP_EOL;
echo '1e10: ' . 1e10 . PHP_EOL;
```

Runs from cli

Output:

```
intval: 10000000000
1e10: 10000000000
```

Ubuntu 12.10 x64 php5.4

In other words, you are using a x86 (32bit) machine.

Comment: 64 bit systems can handle larger ints. Also, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I did not say anything else.