# PHP: various intval() results

Tags: php

I'm a beginner to php and recently saw `intval()` function which "Returns the integer value of var, using the specified base for the conversion".

When I consulted official manual from http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php, it gave an example as follows

```
echo intval(42);                      // 42  
echo intval(4.2);                     // 4  
echo intval('42');                    // 42  
echo intval('+42');                   // 42  
echo intval('-42');                   // -42  
echo intval(042);                     // 34  
echo intval('042');                   // 42  
echo intval(1e10);                    // 1410065408  
echo intval('1e10');                  // 1  
echo intval(0x1A);                    // 26  
echo intval(42000000);                // 42000000  
echo intval(420000000000000000000);   // 0  
echo intval('420000000000000000000'); // 2147483647  
echo intval(42, 8);                   // 42  
echo intval('42', 8);                 // 34  
echo intval(array());                 // 0  
echo intval(array('foo', 'bar'));     // 1
```

How did the answer of `echo intval(1e10);` came up to be 1410065408?

Comment: intval(042) => 34 ??!

Comment: @onetrickpony It's not `042`, it's octal 42.

Comment: @onetrickpony numbers beginning with 0 are treated as **octal**...

Comment: numbers starting with 0 are considered as octal

Comment: I think that 1e10 is to large to be handled correctly by intval...

Comment: @Brewal Yes, you were right - I deleted my comment :)

Comment: The exact result can be system dependent. On my 64-bit system intval(1e10) = 10000000000. This is a an example of numeric overflow on a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer explains it:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13720856/2827152

1e10 exceeds the maximum integer value that can be stored, causing an overflow.

Comment: Not sure if you need certain rep for that but the usual procedure is to vote to close the question as duplicate, so we don't scatter answers to the same question all around the site.