# PHP intval() changes number NOT 2147483647

Tags: php, 32-bit

I'm running PHP 5.3.13 and when I execute

```
php -r "echo intval(9999999999);"
```

It outputs 1410065407.

When I execute

```
php -r "echo intval(PHP_INT_MAX);"
```

It outputs 2147483647.

The smaller integer is causing my code some issues.  Why the difference?

Comment: Change `int` to `bigint` if working in DB - 2147483647 is the largest value for the integer in mysql.

Comment: You answered your own question: it can't represent 9999999999 because it's bigger than PHP_INT_MAX.

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/677639-int-changing-its-own-too-large ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [echo vs echo intval PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720581/echo-vs-echo-intval-php)

Comment: @Boann I guess the issue is that the printed number does not equal the `PHP_INT_MAX` value.

Comment: [Integer overflow!!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, the value `9999999999` is being stored as a `float`.  You can verify this with `var_dump(9999999999)`.  When it's casted to a signed integer, the value is truncated to 32 bits which gives the value `1410065407`.

You can verify this calculation by hand or by using the GMP math extension:

```
$num = gmp_init("9999999999");
$bits = gmp_pow(2, 32);

var_dump(gmp_strval(gmp_mod($num, $bits)));
// string(10) "1410065407"
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense.  I'll accept when I can.  Thanks for the clear answer

Comment: Please explain your calculation. Because `(9999999999 % 2147483647)` is `1410065411` for me: `9999999999  = 4 * 2147483647 + 1410065411`. But: `(9999999999 & 2147483647) = 1410065407`

Comment: Then you should edit your answer, because `PHP_INT_MAX` is actually `2147483647` on 32bit systems. So the calculation is wrong (and impossible to solve on 32bit system anyway)

Comment: @BreyndotEchse - You're totally right.  It's not modulus `PHP_INT_MAX`, it's modulus `2^32`.  Modulus `PHP_INT_MAX` ignores the ~`2^31` negative valid integer values.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
9999999999 (base 10) = 10|01010100000010111110001111111111 (base 2)
1410065407 (base 10) =   |01010100000010111110001111111111 (base 2)
                         ^
                         ------------ 32 bits ------------
```

The first two [most significant bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) get removed. Then you get 1410065407 (base 10)

Answer (score 4):

The binary representation of the integer number 9999999999 is:

```
0010 0101 0100 0000 1011 1110 0011 1111 1111
```

That means you need more that 32 bits to represent that number. If you're using a 32 bit architecture that number will get truncated to

```
0101 0100 0000 1011 1110 0011 1111 1111
```

which represent the integer 1410065407, the value the function is returning.

Answer (score 0):

Your number is to big and causes an overflow. PHP integers are unsigned 32-bit integers. If you want to work with large numbers you could have a look at [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)